# Chrome Automatically Moving Focus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, focus

Got an issue that is specific to Chrome; it's moving the focus from my html inputs to the first user element in a dynamically rendered form.

Example:
HTML_SELECT_00
HTML_SELECT_01
INPUT_TEXT_00

Problem: If you place the cursor in INPUT_TEXT_00 (using the mouse), as soon as you let go of the mouse button, the focus will shift back to HTML_SELECT_00.  If you tab into INPUT_TEXT_00, the focus does not get 'stolen', and works as desired.

This problem does not occur in FF or in IE7/8.  Only in Chrome and my version is up-to-date.

I have two events hooked to the input, onChange and onKeyPress.  However, those events are not triggered simply by placing the cursor in them.

I hope someone has seen this before; I've been searching all over for a resolution.

Regards,
Randall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a `label` wrapping the three elements.

Comment: I'm not sure how the heck you knew that, but that was exactly it.  More specifically I had forgotten to put the closing tag on a label (thereby inadvertently wrapping those other elements).  Thank you very kindly.

Comment: I'd come across exactly the same symptoms myself and puzzled over them at great length!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but there wasn't a label in sight. I fixed this by stopping event bubbling on the mousup event:

```
jQuery("input").mousup(function(event){
    //more code
    //...
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```